# Delete order by using order id and MySQL query

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

How to delete order in magento from order id **100000030** to **100000050** by using **MySQL query**.

Comment: Did you try delete order by programmitically ?

Comment: No,By MySQL query in database.

Comment: do you want to try ? I have code to delete order by programmitically

Comment: ok ,i will be try.

Answer (score 2):

Following Code use to Delete order.

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);

$order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('you_order_id'); 
try {           
    Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order->getIncrementId())->delete();
    echo "Order #" . $id . " is removed" . PHP_EOL;
    Mage::log("Order #" . $id . " is removed", null, "order-delete.log");
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo "Order #" . $id . " could not be remvoved: " . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    Mage::log("Order #" . $id . " could not be remvoved: " . $e->getMessage(), null, "order-delete.log");
}
?>
```

It may be help you.

Here link of [delete order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526914/how-can-i-delete-test-order-from-magento) best way as per your requirement

Comment: It's good but i don't want to delete programmatically.want to delete  by query .

Comment: @KamleshJha I update my answer as per your requirment

Answer (score 2):

Magento, basically store Order details  at below tables

- `sales_flat_order`
- `sales_flat_order_grid`

**if want to remove order then you need  to delete respective table.So run below queries**

> ```
> Delete from sales_flat_order where increment_id in (100000030,100000050)
> Delete from sales_flat_order_grid where increment_id in (100000030,100000050)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`select @order_id:=entity_id from sales_order_entity where increment_id='100000001';
delete from sales_order_entity where entity_id=@order_id or parent_id=@order_id;`

you can try above code for that.

Comment: It is not woking

Answer (score 0):

As the poster wanted to delete a range of orders, those are the queries:

`DELETE FROM sales_flat_order WHERE increment_id >= 100000030 AND increment_id <= 100000050;
DELETE FROM sales_flat_order_grid WHERE increment_id >= 100000030 AND increment_id <= 100000050;`